# how to convert SqlByteString to String [HDBC]

Tags: mysql, haskell, hdbc

I want do something on mysql with hdbc , I want know how can I convert SqlByteString to String? when I try to  use `fromSql bytestrobj`, I got an error

```
<interactive>:20:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue a
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue a => a
*InitPriceTable Database.HDBC Database.HDBC.Types> conn<-connectMySQL defaultMySQLConnectInfo {mysqlUser ="root",mysqlPassword ="root",mysqlDatabase ="linclon"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fromSql` has the type signature

```
fromSql :: Convertible SqlValue a => SqlValue -> a
```

If you just write `fromSql bytestrobj`, Haskell cannot tell which type `a` this expression has. In order to force `a = ByteString` you can supply the type manually:

```
fromSql bytestrobj :: ByteString
```

Example ghci-session:

```
Prelude> :m +Database.HDBC Data.ByteString
Prelude Database.HDBC Data.ByteString> fromSql (toSql "Hello") :: ByteString 
"Hello"
```

If the type can be inferred, then you can drop the type annotation:

```
Prelude Data.ByteString Database.HDBC> Data.ByteString.take 4 (fromSql (toSql "Hello"))
"Hell"
```

Comment: thank you very much,and do you know how to install hdbc with stack ?

Comment: IIRC it is `stack install HDBC` (note the capitalisation)